# How to obtain a local network IP address for a VM running on Vagrant/VIrtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have a VM running on Windows using Virtual Box and Vagrant.

How do I assign a local network IP address to this VM using a local DHCP?

The requirement is for this VM to be visible on the local network and to get the IP address from the local network's DHCP server.

Comment: You must enable **Bridged Adapter**  under Network, instead of NAT.

Answer (score 1):

As MariusMatutiae mentioned, you must switch the Virtual Network from NAT to Bridged. This will allow the VM to interact with other "real" devices on the network.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in your `Vagrantfile`. It will use DHCP by default.

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

Find the new IP address with

```
vagrant ssh
ifconfig
ip address   # CentOS 7
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html

Comment: set `ssh_info_public = true` then `vagrant ssh-info` would show the desired ip address